# Android Pay Braintree Integration

Tags: android, braintree, android-pay

I want to integrate Android Pay Braintree Integration in my android app.I did some of coding but its shows i have to setup my card in android pay app which is unable to download in India Because Android Pay is only available for USA users.So is there any way to integrate android pay in Indian app.

Answer (score 0):

I am mentioning following steps these may be useful for you.

Step 1:- If you are not in us and you want to use android pay then you should have a us(US) registered email id (You can make us email id with help of gmail ) then you can download android pay .

Step2: You can register you credit card (US) in android pay now a days few credit cards are supported by android pay you can try with Visa, Master Card, American Express cards and other cards which support the android pay.

Step 3: Implement following points https://developers.google.com/android-pay/diagrams .

If you have some problem then comment me.